# Iphone - How do you sort an NSMutableArray into ascending order?

Tags: nsmutablearray, nsarray, int

In Xcode i am trying to make a graph into which some points (X,Y) are given by the user.The user can choose how many points he or she wants to plot on the graph. I have stored the X axis points in an NSMutableArray and the Y axis points in an NSMutableArray but now i need to sort these into ascending order so i can fix a bug with the graph when having two points with the same x or y axis plot. The NSMutableArrays contains primitive int's. An example of what i need to do is if i am given 4 coordinates for one of the axis such as 4,8,5,3 i need the array to be sorted into 3,4,5,8

The code below doesn't include the graph generation because it is quite long

Thanks for the help! -

```
int userInputCount;

printf("How many coordinates would you like to plot? ");
scanf("%i", &userInputCount);
printf("\n");

NSMutableArray * xCoordArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray * yCoordArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (int i = 1; i <= userInputCount; i++){
        int xCoord;
        int yCoord;

        printf("(%i) Enter coordinates [X,Y]: ", i);

        scanf("%i,%i", &xCoord, &yCoord);

        NSNumber *xCoordinate =  [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:xCoord];
        NSNumber *yCoordinate =  [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:yCoord];

        [xCoordArray addObject:xCoordinate];
        [yCoordArray addObject:yCoordinate];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

After working on it for a while I figured it out if anybody is trying the same thing

```
for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++){
            for (int i = 0; i < [yCoordArray count] - 1; i++){

                int yExchangeIntOne = [[yCoordArray objectAtIndex:i] intValue];
                int yExchangeIntTwo = [[yCoordArray objectAtIndex:i +1] intValue];
                if (yExchangeIntOne > yExchangeIntTwo){
                    [yCoordArray exchangeObjectAtIndex:i+1 withObjectAtIndex:i];
                    i = 0;
                }

                int xExchangeIntOne = [[xCoordArray objectAtIndex:i] intValue];
                int xExchangeIntTwo = [[xCoordArray objectAtIndex:i +1] intValue];
                if (xExchangeIntOne > xExchangeIntTwo){
                    [xCoordArray exchangeObjectAtIndex:i+1 withObjectAtIndex:i];
                    i = 0;
                }

            }
        }
```

This goes right after the 
    [xCoordArray addObject:xCoordinate]; and the
    [yCoordArray addObject:yCoordinate]; in the loop